# How do I know if I am visiting an anonymous class in ASM?

Tags: anonymous-class, java-bytecode-asm

I have extended the ASM ClassVisitor and want to know if the visited class in an anonymous class.

Since I do have the class file I figured that if the class file name ended with $[1-9][0-9]*.class it would be an anonymous class. But currency characters are valid in class names so for example a class named MyClass$1 would match (classfile is named MyClass$1.class) even though it is not an anonymous class. I know most people would probably not name things like this but it is allowed.

So I thought about overriding the visitOuterClass method to see if it had an outer class that would eliminate outer classes with names ending in $# but still you could have an inner non anonymous class name ending with, for example, $1.

So is there some way in ASM to know that it is visiting an anonymous class? Or a better trick than mine?

# means any number (regexp: [1-9][0-9]*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant criteria is whether the class’ [`InnerClasses` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6) declares the class to be an anonymous inner class. ASM report the contents by calling [`visitInnerClass`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitInnerClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-) for each entry of the attribute, if present.

So you can check it like

```Java
public class CheckForInnerClass extends ClassVisitor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Class<?>[] test={ Object.class, Map.Entry.class, new Object(){}.getClass() };
        for(Class<?> c: test) {
            new ClassReader(c.getName())
                .accept(new CheckForInnerClass(Opcodes.ASM5), ClassReader.SKIP_CODE);
        }
    }

    private String actualName;
    private Boolean anonymous;

    public CheckForInnerClass(int api) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5);
    }
    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access,
        String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        actualName=name;
    }
    @Override
    public void visitInnerClass(String name, String outer, String innerName, int access) {
        if(name.equals(actualName)) {
            anonymous = innerName==null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void visitEnd() {
        System.out.println(actualName+": is "
            + (anonymous==null? "not an": anonymous? "an anonymous": "a named")
            + " inner class");
    }
}
```

which prints

```
java/lang/Object: is not an inner class
java/util/Map$Entry: is a named inner class
CheckForInnerClass$1: is an anonymous inner class
```

Comment: Thank you! Been thinking/googling on this on and off for a few days.